# How do I find the index of an element in an array, vector or slice?

Tags: rust

I need to find an index of an element in a vector of strings. This is what I got so far:

```
fn main() {
    let test: Vec<String> = vec![
        "one".to_string(),
        "two".to_string(),
        "three".to_string(),
        "four".to_string(),
    ];

    let index: i32 = test
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .find(|&r| r.1.to_string() == "two".to_string())
        .unwrap()
        .0;
}
```

It produces an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:9:22
   |
9  |       let index: i32 = test
   |  ______________________^
10 | |         .iter()
11 | |         .enumerate()
12 | |         .find(|&r| r.1.to_string() == "two".to_string())
13 | |         .unwrap()
14 | |         .0;
   | |__________^ expected i32, found usize
```

I assume that's because `enumerate()` returns a tuple of `(usize, _)` (correct me if I'm wrong), but how do I convert `usize` to `i32` here? If there is a better approach, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I think you should look at the [`position`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) method instead.

```
fn main() {
    let test = vec!["one", "two", "three"];
    let index = test.iter().position(|&r| r == "two").unwrap();
    println!("{}", index);
}
```

You can [test it here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7cff7ae21633fbd830741cd4be1569b7).

Note that this works for any iterator, so it can be used for vectors, arrays, and slices, all of which produce iterators.

Comment: `|r| *r == target` or I got "cannot move out of a shared reference"

Answer (score 75):

**TLDR** Use an iterator with the `position` method, the Rust docs [shows a good example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position).

---

No, it's because indices are `usize`, not `i32`.  In fact, `i32` is completely inappropriate for this purpose; it may not be large enough, and there's no reason for it to be signed.  Just use `usize`.

Some other notes: calling `to_string()` is not free, and you don't need it for the comparison; you can compare string slices just fine!

Also, if you *really* want to turn a `usize` into an `i32`, you can do that with a cast: `x as i32`, though this will *not* produce an error on over- or under-flow (*i.e.* the result may be negative).

All that said, as noted in Mathieu David's answer, there's a [`position`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) method on iterators that does what you want.