# Array binary_search method missing elements in array

Tags: rust

New to rust, and i tumble on something i don't get.

Given an array of &str, the method `binary_search` miss elements that are within the array.

I must do something wrong but can't figure out what.

```rust
const CARDS_AS_STR: [&'static str; 52] = [
    "2c", "2d", "2h", "2s", "3c", "3d", "3h", "3s", "4c", "4d", "4h", "4s",
    "5c", "5d", "5h", "5s", "6c", "6d", "6h", "6s", "7c", "7d", "7h", "7s",
    "8c", "8d", "8h", "8s", "9c", "9d", "9h", "9s", "Tc", "Td", "Th", "Ts",
    "Jc", "Jd", "Jh", "Js", "Qc", "Qd", "Qh", "Qs", "Kc", "Kd", "Kh", "Ks",
    "Ac", "Ad", "Ah", "As",
];

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", CARDS_AS_STR.binary_search(&"9c"));              // Ok(28)
    println!("{:?}", CARDS_AS_STR.binary_search(&"Kc"));              // Err(40) ?
    println!("{:?}", CARDS_AS_STR.binary_search(&CARDS_AS_STR[36]));  // Err(32) ?¿?
}
```

I've tried `binary_search_by` to end up with the same result.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07b7796c56abdb0ee4ab8b71d3258274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search only works on sorted arrays, your's isn't. Using:

```rust
const CARDS_AS_STR: [&'static str; 52] = [
    "2c", "2d", "2h", "2s", "3c", "3d", "3h", "3s", "4c", "4d", "4h", "4s", "5c", "5d", "5h", "5s",
    "6c", "6d", "6h", "6s", "7c", "7d", "7h", "7s", "8c", "8d", "8h", "8s", "9c", "9d", "9h", "9s",
    "Ac", "Ad", "Ah", "As", "Jc", "Jd", "Jh", "Js", "Kc", "Kd", "Kh", "Ks", "Qc", "Qd", "Qh", "Qs",
    "Tc", "Td", "Th", "Ts",
];
```

Will work

Comment: Thanks a lot should have known that - guess a bit confused while starting with rust lol

But since array do not have a find method how could i search in the array @Mikdore ?

Comment: I need the array to be in the original order though

Comment: @zedryas see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558246/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-vector-or-slice